# How do I programmatically access a Storage Container inside an Azure Media Service?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-storage-account

How do I programmatically access a Storage Container inside an Azure Media Service?

My ultimate goal is to get access to each individual asset's storage container, and the files within.

I do have access to the Storage Account through the Portal, but I need to do this programmatically with C#.

I'm still a bit new to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

- A storage account is required for any Azure Storage access.
- Media Services provides SDK-level tools that allows you to manage multiple storage accounts and load balance asset distribution during upload to these accounts based on metrics or random distribution.
- An AccessPolicy specifies the read, write, and list rights as well as the duration of access to an asset.
- Please refer to these references for more information:
  [Media Services documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/)
  [Access Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-concepts#access-policy)
  [Storage Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-concepts#storage-account)